# to belie = to betray?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I suspect that the verb **to belie** here is used to mean **to betray**. Is that true?

> You don’t get a pat on the back for ratcheting down from rabid after
>   exploiting that very radicalism to your advantage. Unrepentant
>   opportunism **belies** a staggering lack of character and caring that
>   can’t simply be vanquished from memory. You did real harm to this
>   country and many of its citizens, and I will never — never — forget
>   that.

[No, Trump, We Can’t Just Get Along](http://www.nytimes.com/2016/11/23/opinion/no-trump-we-cant-just-get-along.html?src=me)

However, doesn't belie mean, at its core, **to contradict**. Here's what [COBUILD Advanced English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/belie) has to say about belie.

1. If one thing belies another, it hides the true situation and so creates a false idea or image of someone or something. [V n] ⇒ *Her looks belie her 50 years.*
2. If one thing belies another, it proves that the other thing is not true or genuine. [V n] ⇒ *The facts of the situation belie his testimony.*

I am struggling to align the definitions in the dictionary with the way the verb is used by the NY Times article.

Comment: Nice catch! Mr. Blow blew it. *Belie* means give the lie to, contradict, or disprove. So you would expect some notion in contrast to opportunism, e.g., *unrepentant opportunism **belies** a claim of charitable feeling*. The proper word here is *betrays*, i.e, reveals.

Comment: deadrat is dead right.

Please also note that it can’t be "vanquished" from memory; it could be, for instance, "banished" or "expunged" from memory, meaning "cast out [of[" but "vanquished" means defeated…

Then would you trust one who misused an outstanding term like "vanquished" to use any other verb correctly?

Comment: Belie is commonly used to mean "hide": [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/belie) says "to show something to be false, or to hide something such as an emotion". Purists will object, but this sort of process keeps on happening.

Answer (score 2):

The word *belie* has two common meanings (**1** to misrepresent; **2** to give the lie to, that is, to be inconsistent with the veracity of a claim or facade), and, as deadrat has pointed out, always suggests some contrast between its subject and object.

On the other hand, when the subject of the word *betray* isn't a sentient being, the word always means to reveal.

So, I agree that in that NYT excerpt, ‘belies’ ought to be replaced with ‘betrays’.

Corresponding examples:

✔️ His calm voice **belies** his nervousness.
❌ His calm voice betrays his nervousness.

✔️ His trembling hands **belie** his calm voice.
❌ His trembling hands betray his calm voice.

❌ His trembling hands belie his nervousness.
✔️ His trembling hands **betray** his nervousness.

Answer (score 1):

Etymologically speaking, it's the same thing.
Curiously enough, *belie* comes from the Old English word *beleogan*, which meant "to deceive by lies". This, through a bunch of Germanic languages, can be followed back to the Proto-Indo-European root *leugh*, "to tell a lie". *Betray* has the same prefix root as *belie*, but its root can be traced to the Latin word *trans* (and further back, the PIE word *tere*), both meaning "across", implying that a betrayer switches sides. If one who switches sides can be equated with one who tells lies (and in both marriage and espionage, it *is* applicable), then in diachronic linguistics it is the same thing.
The Cambridge English Dictionary defines *belie* as "to represent falsely or hide something", and in many cases this is the same as betrayal.
I vote yes.
(My heart goes out to etymonline for this explanation)

Comment: For the same reasons you cited, I came to the opposite conclusion.  Belie focuses on concealing, whereas betray focuses on harm.

Comment: I think _belie_ can be encompassed in _betray_; therefore they can be used in the same sense, though _belie_ is more specific

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/belie) offering best brings out the sense in play here:

> - **belie** [verb; transitive]
>
> ...
>
> [3] [disguise, sense [3]]
>
> *An air of rural charm … belies the community's industrial activity*. —American Guide Series: Pennsylvania

and

> **disguise**
>
> ...
>
> [3]: to obscure the existence or true state or character of: conceal
>
> *unable to disguise his true feelings* [[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disguise)]

So not 'exposes/betrays'; on the contrary, 'masks'.

But the NYT would then be labelling 'unrepentant opportunism' here as at least approaching acceptable ('a ratcheting down from "rabid" ').